# How to get input from user display in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I encounter a problem to display input from user into this table.

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-class-even="'bg-light-grey'" ng-if="isLoading==false">
                <td>
                    <div> {{user.username}} </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div> {{user.name}} </div>
                </td>
 </tr>
```

If user click this "edit user" button, the form will appear.

```
 <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" ng-click="editUser();">
```

This is form that require user to fill edit their username and name

```
  <div class="dialog-contents">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit User</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form name="edituser">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="editUser.username.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="Username">Username</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="username" ng-model="user.username" class="form-control" id="Username" placeholder="Enter Username"/>
                </div>
                <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"
                      ng-class="addUser.username.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="editUser.name.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="Name">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="name" ng-model="user.name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name"/>
                </div>
                <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"
                      ng-class="addUser.name.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
            </div>
```

Form this form, if user click this "submit" button, the user details will appear in table as i provide the code above.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add();"
                ng-class="isLoading ? 'disabled' : '';">Submit </button>
```

Now, i want to push the input from user, and display it in the table. But i am stuck in developing the controller to get the input and displayed it. Appreciate if someone can help solve this problem.

```
 app.register('user', ['$scope', 'ngDialog', function ($scope, $dialog) {

$scope.isLoading = false;
$scope.addUser = function(){
    $dialog.open({
            showClose: false,
            closeByEscape: true,
            template: 'view/user/user-user-add.html',
            controller: ['$scope', function ($dialogScope) {
                $dialogScope.users = {
                    username : "" ,
                    name : "",
                    status : "",
                }
                .closePromise.then(function (data) 
                $dialogScope.hasError = false;
                $dialogScope.errorMessage = '';
                $dialogScope.add=function(){
                    $dialogScope.closeThisDialog({username:"xxx"});
                }
            }]
        });
    };
 }]);
```

Comment: you have defined the function as `adduser ` and onclick button function is `add()` check it

Comment: checked it. and tried. the problem that i encounter now i think is with the controller. if i click "edit user" button, nothing appear

Answer (score 0):

In your add function, close the dialog and pass the new user object to close promise, like this: -

```
//your dialog controller
$dialogScope.add=function(){
    $dialogScope.closeThisDialog({username:"xxx"});
};
```

you main controller: -

```
$scope.addUser = function(){
  $dialog.open({
        ....
    })
  .closePromise.then(function (data) {
      console.log(data); 
      //check and find user from the data and do what you need, i.e. $scope.users.push(user);
   });
};
```

Comment: i am still stuck here. i edited the controller part. appreciate if u could help me @sdfacre

Comment: where were you stuck? it'd be easier if you could create a plunker.

Comment: ...your plunker should have at least been working...anyway, I think you misplaced the code. check this one I just created. http://plnkr.co/edit/MOlsu1C0we8pniRFGEiY?p=preview